# Docker keycloak dynamic web app not working

Tags: java, docker, web-applications, keycloak, tomcat8

```
webapp: port : 7070  and   docker: jboss/keycloak port:2020
```

keycloak.json

```json
{
  "realm": "abc",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:2020/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  "resource": "abcclient",
  "public-client": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

`http://localhost:2020/auth/realms/abcWeb/.well-known/openid-configuration` : can see in browser the output  but error.org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls Failed to load URLs from `http://localhost:2020/auth/realms/abcWeb/.well-known/openid-configuration`

keycloak standalone server:
***valid redirect urlis localhost:7070/****
base/admin url : localhost:2020/

in web.xml  of app

```
        <login-config>
            <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
            <realm-name>realmname</realm-name>
        </login-config>
        
        <security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>webapp</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin</role-name>
            </auth-constraint>
        
        </security-constraint>
        <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
        <security-role>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </security-role>
        <security-role>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role>
```

*) in META_INF add a xml file named (contex.xml)

```
      <Context path="/path to your app">
            <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>
        </Context>
```

*) build and run ()
note be careful while configuring valid return url while creating client in keycloak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the after endless attempts i succeeded.  Built and ran the image for my web app in docker container.
checked within the bash of tomcat and observed how my welcome file was built and difference in how i managed my folder structure.
my WEB-INF and META_INF are now under the root directory.

```
-- main app/
  --apps
    - classes
--Dockerfile
--WEB_INF
--META_INF
--pom.xml
```

not sure if this the correct way but it worked !!!